# Combine multiple lines onto one line

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query

```
SELECT orderno,
CASE WHEN param_id = 'variant' THEN param_val END AS 'variant',
CASE WHEN param_id = 'period_from' THEN param_val END AS'period_from',
CASE WHEN param_id = 'period_to' THEN param_val END AS'period_to',
CASE WHEN param_id = 'division' THEN param_val END AS 'division',
CASE WHEN param_id = 'show_div' THEN param_val END AS 'show_div',
CASE WHEN param_id = 'group_div' THEN param_val END AS 'group_div',
FROM orderreport

order by orderno
```

This returns a grid similar to the below (there are another number of columns which I have removed for the purpose of the question)  There is also an infinite number of order nos

```
orderno |   variant | period_from | period_to | division | show_div | group_div
3 | AH003 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL
3 | NULL    | 201300 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL
3 | NULL    | NULL | 201304 | NULL | NULL   | NULL
3 | NULL    | NULL | NULL | SALES | NULL | NULL
3 | NULL    | NULL | NULL | NULL | Y | NULL
3 | NULL    | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | Y
```

My desired output is as the below, no matter what i have tried I am stumped.

```
orderno | variant | period_from | period_to | division | show_div | group_div
3| AH003    |  201300   |  201304   | SALES  |  Y  | Y
```

Comment: You need to provide details about the data in orderreport.  Are you seeking the maximum of these values, etc.  Will you always only have one row with a non-null value for that column.  It is strange that you get multiple rows for the single orderno... do you have some JOINS that are not being shown?

Comment: If the only choices are the one value or null, then you can apply any min or max to exclude the nulls.  But as Darrin said, that's some funny looking data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query is very close, I would add an aggregate function around your CASE expressions and then a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT orderno,
    max(CASE WHEN param_id = 'variant' THEN param_val END) AS variant,
    max(CASE WHEN param_id = 'period_from' THEN param_val END) AS period_from,
    max(CASE WHEN param_id = 'period_to' THEN param_val END) AS period_to,
    max(CASE WHEN param_id = 'division' THEN param_val END) AS division,
    max(CASE WHEN param_id = 'show_div' THEN param_val END) AS show_div,
    max(CASE WHEN param_id = 'group_div' THEN param_val END) AS group_div
FROM orderreport
group by orderno
order by orderno
```

Comment: This will only work if for any given column there is only 1 non-null value.  That's a pretty risky assumption.

Comment: @Andrew That can be easily rectified by using `row_number()`, since this is a essentially a PIVOT, you can get the result a number of ways.  It really depends on the data and the final desired result.  It they have multiple possible values for any of the columns, then added a row_number an you can get the result.

Comment: I guess that's my point though, I don't think we know enough to propose an answer yet

Comment: @Andrew I'm not going to argue with you but based on their data and their query, then this should resolve their issue.

Comment: @Andrew based on Jim's response ... I guess we did

Comment: +1 to Jims question because he showed appreciation for the answer.